# How to design a dynamic page in Orchard?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms-1.6

I am developing an IT company's home website using orchard CMS. It has 8 different pages with Header and Footer remaining same throughout. I have created home page in Orchard from the admin panel using widgets and modules. I am confused how do i create pages like Team, Services, About us. I know I can create pages using simple HTML editor provided in CMS. But the page has few widgets and modules defined. I am not sure how to place them on other pages. I am also aware about Layering in CMS. But, I don't think so that will help. Could some one direct me to a proper guide about creating multiple dynamic pages with different modules on each page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear to me, so allow me you give you an outline...

First, you should create a new theme in Orchard. There are a lot of tutorials on how to do this, for example:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-new-theme

After you created this theme, copy over all files in "views" and "styles" from the default theme (called TheThemeMachine) to your new theme to get a decent starting point. Finally set the new theme as current in the Orchard dashboard.

In your theme you can find "Layout.cshtml". That's the master view. Everything you put in there will render on all pages. So this is where you will typically place your header and footer stuff.

For each page, you need to create a seperate page. Main content goes into the html editor you mentioned.

Widgets are bound to layers. Layers can be bound to a url. So if you need a widget on one page only, create a layer with a url-rule then drop the widget on that layer.

If you need more specific advice, please clearly state what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well, It did answered my question. I was looking for, How to create Layers and use them with url rule.

Comment: See the section "adding a layer" on this page, it has all the information you need:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Managing-widgets#AddingaLayer